# Elastic Search - Generic Value Passed In

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch

I am currently implementing a RESTful API for Elastic Search. Is there a way to query ES with a generic value? For example, this will allow the user to pass in any key and value and this would convert the value to whatever typeof field it is. I feel like I am complicating it. Is there a simpler way to query ES with generic values being passed to it?

Ex:

I could pass the following: POST command -

RulesGreaterThanDictionary is :

```
  public Dictionary<string, Object> RulesGreaterThanDictionary { get; set; }
```

And the POST call is :

```
  {
        "RuleEquals":
        {
          "RulesEqualDictionary":
          {
            "email" : "ggg@gmail.com",
            "validUser" : true
          }
        },
          "RuleGreaterThan" : 
        {
            "RulesGreaterThanDictionary" : 
            {
              "minamount" : 10
            }
        }
    }
```

As this would query ES to find documents that have email equal to some email, and is a valid user as well as the minamount of the item is at least 10.

Something generic like that.

Has this already been implemented before?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to write a wrapper

```
public class ValueWrapper {
    ... 
    public static final String VALUE = "value";

    private T value;

    // getter & setter
}
```

and than map the wrapper instead of you object which can be gerneric :)